# Confusion about custom data types and Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Quant = Single | Multiple deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

data ListUnit = ListUnit {
    quant :: Quant,
    num :: Int,
    letter :: Char
    } deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

data ListUnit2 = ListUnit2 Quant Int Char deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

decodeModified :: Quant -> Int -> Char -> Char
decodeModified _ _ ls = ls

decodeModified2 :: ListUnit2 -> Char
decodeModified2 _ _ ls = ls
```

I'm new to data types in Haskell. I'm wondering why ListUnit works but I'm having problems with ListUnit2. I know I shouldn't have to break out all of ListUnits values like I do in the first instance. But when I don't, GHC that I'm not passing enough arguments. I don't see how what I'm doing is different than LYAH in the [Shapes example](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

In case anyone is wondering, this is for "99 Problems" #11. The data I want to model is `[Multiple 4 'a',Single 'b',Multiple 2 'c', Multiple 2 'a',Single 'd',Multiple 4 'e']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
decodeModified2 :: ListUnit2 -> Char
```

means "`decodeModified2` takes a `ListUnit2`<sub>*(type)*</sub> and returns a `Char`", whereas this:

```
decodeModified2 _ _ ls = ls
```

means "`decodeModified2` takes three arguments, discarding the first two and returning the third". These two statements are incompatible.

I think what you meant to write is:

```
decodeModified2 (ListUnit2 _ _ ls) = ls
```

which means "`decodeModified2` takes a value constructed by `ListUnit2`<sub>*(function)*</sub> with three arguments, discarding the first two and returning the third".

Does that make sense?

---

**Edited to add** after your comment below: And similarly, when you *call* `decodeModified2`, you need to pass an instance of `ListUnit2`<sub>*(type)*</sub>. For example, you can write something like `decodeModified2 (ListUnit2 3 's' 'x')`, using the value constructor `ListUnit2`<sub>*(function)*</sub> to create an instance of `ListUnit2`<sub>*(type)*</sub>. (Or, more interestingly: you can create an instance of `ListUnit2`<sub>*(type)*</sub> in one place and then call `decodeModified2` in a different place, passing said instance.)

Comment: That does make sense--I'd tried doing something similar at one point, only with TypeUnit2 on the outside of the parentheses. However, even though this type checks I actually get an error at runtime. 

`Couldn't match expected type a0 -> Char -> t0'
                with actual type `Char'
    The function decodeModified2' is applied to three arguments,
    but its type ListUnit2 -> Char' has only one

Couldn't match expected type ListUnit2' with actual type Quant'
    In the first argument of decodeModified2', namely Single'`

// I don't know how to make this not look terrible.

Comment: @Chris: I've expanded my answer to explain how to call this function. I've also added *(type)* and *(function)* after each time I mention `ListUnit2`, because I think the two distinct uses of `ListUnit2` might be part of what's confusing you: it's used both as a *type constructor*, analogously to `Quant` in your first example, and as a *value constructor*, (mostly) analogously to `Single` or `Multiple` in your first example.